# CSS Relative 2 times and Absolute Postioning

Tags: html, css

Can i used relative
2 times in my css code
This is possible or is it a mistake
here is my code :
Thanks for any help

My CSS

```
#box1 {
width: 800px;
height: 600px;
background-color: #FF0004;
margin-right: auto;
margin-left: auto;
position: relative;
}

    #box2 {
width: 380px;
height: 256px;
background-color: #A9FF00;
position: relative;
left: 7px;
top: 10px;
}

        #box3 {
width: 190px;
height: 155px;
background-color: orange;
position: absolute;
left: 13px;
top: 15px;
}
```

My HTML

```
<div id="box1"><div id="box2"><div id="box3"></div></div></div>
```

Comment: the first relative is useless here but it's not a mistake

Comment: Why do you want the `#box1` element to be positioned relative?

Comment: Do you offer to make it to static ?

Comment: @user1780343 There is nothing wrong with code, it's completely valid but why do you want it to be positioned relative? What is the reason?

Comment: I just assumed that it must be set to the body element